# How do I generate grid of 7x7 given an array of objects in a sequence?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects say like this

```Js
var card = [
    {name:'square',color:'red'},
    {name:'triangle',color:'black'},
    {name:'circle',color:'blue'},
    {name:'oval',color:'yellow'},
    {name:'pentagon',color:'green'}
]
```

I want to generate a grid of 7x7 in horizontal sequence as per the shapes above and show the name of each, since the array only has 5 objects, I'd like to after 5th element, start from the first object again, say like this

```Js
SQUARE   | TRIANGLE |  CIRCLE  |   OVAL   | PENTAGON |  SQUARE  | TRIANGLE
CIRCLE   |   OVAL   | PENTAGON |  SQUARE  | TRIANGLE |  CIRCLE  | OVAL
PENTAGON |  SQUARE  | TRIANGLE |  CIRCLE  |   OVAL   | PENTAGON | SQUARE
TRIANGLE |  CIRCLE  |   OVAL   | PENTAGON |  SQUARE  | TRIANGLE | CIRCLE
OVAL     | PENTAGON |  SQUARE  | TRIANGLE |  CIRCLE  |   OVAL   | PENTAGON
SQUARE   | TRIANGLE |  CIRCLE  |   OVAL   | PENTAGON |  SQUARE  | TRIANGLE
CIRCLE   |   OVAL   | PENTAGON |  SQUARE  | TRIANGLE |  CIRCLE  | OVAL
```

Comment: you'll need a nested for loop ... and the modulo `%` operator

Comment: @JaromandaX no need for a nested loop, although it makes the job easier

Comment: for a two dimensional "output" I can't see a single loop as being at all preferable, better or easier to read than a nested loop - no need for ANY loop if you want to write poor code

Comment: although, now that the input and expected output has changed in the question, I can see how a single loop is actually the preferred solution :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `<table>` you can do it per the example below. The offset into your array is calculated with:

```
((i * 7 ) + j) % 5
```

I changed your colours to make the output more readable.

```js
var card = [
  {name:'square',color:'pink'},
  {name:'triangle',color:'lightgrey'},
  {name:'circle',color:'lightblue'},
  {name:'oval',color:'yellow'},
  {name:'pentagon',color:'lightgreen'}
];

var table = document.getElementById('grid');

for(var i=0; i<7; i++) {
  row = grid.insertRow(-1);
  for(var j=0; j<7; j++) {
    cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.innerHTML = card[((i*7)+j) % 5].name;
    cell.style.backgroundColor = card[((i*7)+j) % 5].color;
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="grid">
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The modulo or [remainder operator (`%`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) can take care of this:

```js
var card = [
  {name:'square',color:'pink'},
  {name:'triangle',color:'lightgrey'},
  {name:'circle',color:'lightblue'},
  {name:'oval',color:'yellow'},
  {name:'pentagon',color:'lightgreen'}
];

function generateTable(grid, rows, cols) {
  var row;
  var cells = rows * cols;
  for(var i=0; i < cells; i++){
    // track row length and insert new ones when necessary
    // also creates the first row
    if(i % cols == 0) {
      row = grid.insertRow(-1);
    }
    // track our position in the card list
    // modulo operator lets us loop through the cards repeatedly
    var thisCard = card[i % card.length];
    cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.innerHTML = thisCard.name;
    cell.style.backgroundColor = thisCard.color;
  }
}

generateTable(document.getElementById('grid'), 7, 7);
```

```html
<table id="grid">
</table>
```